# Is there a way to extract entire column as a vector with double brackets in R? [[]]

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the entire column from a dataframe but as their datatype instead of a dataframe.

```
> athletes_BMI_sorted[[1:10,"NOC"]]

Error: Must extract row with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `1:10` has size 10 but must be size 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: What about using simple brackets? Is it what you want? What d you mean by "as their datatype"?

Comment: I think `df$NOC[1:10]` is your disired.

Comment: Try `iris[1:10,"Sepal.Length"]`or `iris$Sepal.Length[1:10]`

Comment: Double brackets always extract a single column as a vector, but you can't also do row subsetting inside those brackets. `athletes_BMI_sorted[["NOC"]]` is a vector. `athletes_BMI_sorted[["NOC"]][1:10]` is the first 10 entries of that vector.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.